# in ReactJS does a <button> needs to be in <form>? Also what is the diff between <div onClick> and <button onClick>?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

just a (hopefully) simple question.
I made a reactjs app where I use `<button>` as follows:

```
<div>
  <button> Hello, Click Me </button>
</div>
```

And when I checked in the inspector, a `<form>` is added and everything looks like this:

```
<form>
  <div>
    <button>Hello, Click Me</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

My questions therefore are:

1. Should a `<button>`, like `<input>` be always enclosured in a `<form>`?

Because like in the examples shown on this page: [LINK](https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_events.asp) the buttons are not enclosured in `<form>`.

2. What is the difference between `<div onClick={something}>Something</div>` and `<button onClick={somethingNew}>Something New</button>`?

Comment: What libraries are you using? I haven't seen this behavior in React before.

Comment: Neither an `<input>` nor a `<button>` is _required_ to be in a `<form>` if you are using javascript to manage their behavior. If you want standard form submit and behavior then they will need to be in a form. However, putting the controls within a form does benefit _accessibility_, because assistive technology like a screen reader then _"knows"_ it is working in a form and can give appropriate cues to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No it is not mandatory to keep a button inside a form. You can use it outside a form to. It needs to be enclosed by a `<form>` in case where you are sending the form data using any request.
2. The difference between `<div onClick={something}>Something</div>` and `<button onClick={somethingNew}>Something New</button>` is that providing onClick on a div will keep that function for the entire container that holds your elements. But keeping it on a specified element that is in this case your button will just apply to the button and not the entire container.